# Folland's proof of Maximal Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I am studying Differentiation of Measures and Function from Folland's Real Analysis and [these notes](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Eborell/MeasureTheory.pdf). I am trying to fill up the details of certain arguments that Folland provides. [image: maximal theorem]

In second line of the proof, the author says the balls cover $E_\alpha$. Here's what I have done to justify this statement however I am bit *skeptical*:

We need to show that $E_{\alpha}=\cup_{x\in E_\alpha} B(x,r_{x})$. Folland, in the previous line, showed that for each $x\in E_{\alpha}$, there is some $r_{x}>0$ such that $A_{r_{x}}|f|(x)>\alpha$.

We first show that $B(x,r_{x}) \subset E_{\alpha}$. Let $y \in B(x,r_{x})$. By the previous line, there must be some $r_{y}>0$ such that $A_{r_{y}} |f| (y) > \alpha$.

Consider the following:
\begin{align*}
     Hf(y) &= \sup_{r>0} A_{r} |f|(y) \\
     &\ge A_{r_{y}} |f|(y) > \alpha.
 \end{align*}
Hence $y\in E_{\alpha}$. Running $x$ over $E_{\alpha}$, we have that $E=\cup_{x\in E_{\alpha}} B(x,r_{x})$.

---

Although my argument looks okay to me, I never used the fact that $y\in B(x,r_x)$. Can someone correct me I am wrong?

Comment: If you're choosing a ball $B(x,r_x)$ for _each_ $x\in E_\alpha$, then surely the balls $B(x,r_x)$ cover $E_\alpha$ - for any given $x\in E_\alpha$, it lies in the member $B(x,r_x)$ of the cover. Am I missing something?

Comment: @csch2 You're right but that shows that $E_\alpha \subset \cup_{x\in E_\alpha} B(x,r_x)$. I wanted the other inclusion though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equation right before Theorem 3.17, and we see that

$$
E_\alpha= (Hf)^{-1}((\alpha,\: +\infty)) = \bigcup_{r>0}(A_r\vert f\vert)^{-1}((\alpha,\: +\infty))
$$

If $x$ is in LHS, then it belongs to some open set $A_r|f|^{-1}((\alpha,\: +\infty))$ Use the continuity wrt $x$ of $A_r|f|(x)$ from Lemma 3.16 to obtain a $r_x>0$. This ball $B(r_x,x)$ is a subset of $A_r\vert f\vert^{-1}((\alpha,\: +\infty))$. The rest follows.